# Java doc comments Format

Tags: javadoc

I was seeing this kind of java class level documentation for some classes in projects. can any one please let me know is there any way that this format can be automatically generated or is this format created by developers.

```
/**
 * 
//**************************************************************************************************
//**************************************************************************************************
//                      Copyright (c) 2013 by XXXXX
//                              ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
//**************************************************************************************************
//**************************************************************************************************
//
//  Project name            : XXXXX
//  Class Name              : XXXXXX
//  Date                    : 26th  Feb 2013
//  Author                  : XXXXXX
//  Version                 : 1.0                          
//
//***************************************************************************************************
//  Class Description:
//This class is for calling DroidGap API.
//***************************************************************************************************
//  Update history: 
//  Date :      5/03/13     Developer Name :XXXXXX     Modification Comments : .
//
//***************************************************************************************************

 * 
 */
```

Comment: Depends entirely on which IDE you are using, but it's not hard to just cut-and-paste from previous files.

Comment: Yes, We can cut-and-paste it but with intrest I am willing to know. I am using eclipse IDE but as per my knowledge eclipse is not generating the above format by default. @Jeff-InventorChromeOS

Comment: Check under the preferences under Java | Editor. If its possible to configure, it'll be under that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Comments > Types. But I would strongly advise you to stick to the standard doc comment format. If this format is dictated by the PHBs, put it in a non-Javadoc block comment at the top of the file and use standard doc comments on the actual class and methods.